# How to calculate separable closures of an algebraic extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

In my study of fields, the notion of the separability of an algebraic field extension is one of the more slippery concepts I have encountered thusfar. What is particularly vexing to me is the notion of a separable closure. Let $E/F$ be an algebraic field extension. The separable closure of $F$ in $E$ is defined to be the subfield

$E_{sep}=\{\alpha \in E \; | \; \alpha $ is separable over $ F \}$.

While the concept of a separable closure is easy enough to understand based on the definition, the actual calculation of a separable closure $E_{sep}$ for a given algebraic field extension $E/F$ is not obvious to me.

For example, I was recently assigned the following problem:

> Let $k=\mathbb{F}_2(t)$, $\alpha$ be a root of $X^4+tX^2+t\in k[X]$ in an algebraic closure of $k$ and $K=k(\alpha)$, where $\mathbb{F_2}=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Determine $K_{sep}$ and $[K_{sep}:K]$.

My first thought is that since the separability of an element $a$ of the algebraic field extension $E/F$ is defined based on the structure of its minimal polynomial $m_{a,F}(X) \in F[X]$, we can use this to determine the elements of $E_{sep}$. An element $e \in E$ is inseparable if and only if $m_{e,F}(X)=g(X^p)$ for some separable $g(X) \in F[X]$. So the separable elements of $E$ are those whose minimal polynomial is not an element of $F[X^p]$. This, however, does not seems to be a tractable idea.

My questions are

> How does one approach the problem of calculation the separable closure of an algebraic extension, like, for example, the one above?
>
> If there is no general, one-size-fits-all method, what are some examples of techniques used to deduce the separable closure?

Note: any questions asked herein are not current homework questions.

Comment: I don't know of any general approaches, but I do see that for this particular question, $\alpha^2$ is separable over $k$ because its minimal polynomial is $X^2+tX+t$, hence $k(\alpha^2)/k$ is a separable extension, and because $[K:k(\alpha^2)]=2$ is prime the only extension larger than $k(\alpha^2)$ is $K$ itself, so there is no larger extension that is separable over $k$ than $k(\alpha^2)$ because $K/k$ is inseparable.

Comment: Dear Holdsworth88, a minor terminological point : the  field  $E_{sep}$ is called the separable closure  *of $F$* in $E$ and not the separable closure of $E$ (which would be, logically enough,  a field *larger* than $E$).

Comment: Georges, I have fixed the notation. Thank you for pointing out the inconsistency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few details, completing Zev's completely correct, succinct comment (which I upvoted, of course).

An important first  remark is that the polynomial $f(X)=X^4+tX^2+t\in k[X]$ is irreducible over $k=\mathbb F_2(t)=Frac (\mathbb F_2[t])$ : this is Eisenstein's criterion in all its splendour,  applied with  the prime $t\in \mathbb F_2[t].\:$    Hence  $[K:k]=4$.
The polynomial $g(X)=X^2+tX+t\in k[X]$ is then also irreducible , so that $\alpha^2$ is of degree $2$ over $k$, since it is killed by $g$.
 Moreover since $g$ is  not a polynomial in $X^2$   *and is irreducible* ( an important, often forgotten condition!) , it is separable over $k$ and  so is  $\alpha ^2$, one of its roots.

So we have the tower of quadratic extensions  $k\subset k(\alpha ^2)\subset K$ with $k\subset k(\alpha ^2)$ separable and $k(\alpha ^2)\subset K=k(\alpha )$ obviously purely inseparable.
Only one intermediate field of $k\subset K$  can perform both these feats: $K_{sep}$ .
 Hence  $K_{sep}=k(\alpha^2)$.

Comment: This is why I like algebra so much. Thank you for expanding upon that.

Comment: I am happy to learn that you like algebra so much, Holdsworth88: we sure are in a club to be proud of!